# Netbeans 8.2 execution not stopping at the break point

Tags: java, netbeans

I am using a **Netbeans 8.2** for a Netbeans module application in java.
Netbeans debugging was working fine until now. But currently I am facing problem in debugging the application. The set break point is not getting displayed in the breakpoint window and the execution also does not stop at the break point.

**My netbeans breakpoint window :**

[image: My netbeans breakpoint window]

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Netbeans version 8.0.2, I've encountered a similar problem and problems of freezing on startup, opening projects whilst using Netbeans 8.2 , but after I installed the version I mentioned, I have no problem till now.